# Exocrine system + endocrine system =?

Tags: terminology, endocrinology

What is the title name for **endocrine system + exocrine system**?

In another language that I speak they are called "secretion system" but in English the term secretion system is different and it is about proteins in Gram-negative bacteria. 
[image]

Comment: Since it would be a collection of all glands I would call it as **Glandular System** same as vascular system which includes blood vessels.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Based on this article, it seems that glandular system is a synonym for endocrine system. Isn't it? https://fmidr.com/glandular-system/

Comment: I don't think so because, in one of the heading it has written Endocrine system in a bracket beside glandular system, which can be interpreted as endocrine is a subset of glandular system. Thats my view. Try google ngram

Comment: Ok, after some searching and activation of my logic, I accept it. You can write it here as an answer of course.

Comment: *"Glandular system"* is not a valid name for that combination. There is not a single book on medical physiology (Guyton, Ganong, etc..) using that term.

Comment: We can coin our own term too.

Comment: As long as in any publication or communication you define your meaning of "glandular system",, it seems like a pretty reasonable term to use for convenience. As far as a conventional term already established in the literature, I'm not aware of any.